# Cannot launch Team Fortress 2 because of some OpenGL error

Tags: macos, gpu, driver, games

I want to preface that I know next to nothing about computers, I watch youtube and search stuff on google, but other than that I am clueless. So I am trying to play Team Fortress 2 on my Apple PowerBook G4 550 on Steam. I launch the game and it gives me this message:

> Error Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card in unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.

I haven't the foggiest idea what this means, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to happen. You'll need a newer computer to run games from Steam.

The Powerbook G4 you're trying to use was released in October 2001. Team Fortress 2 was released for macOS in 2010, nine years later. It never supported PowerPC systems, which had not been produced since late 2006.